# PyQt5 fbs can't execute slack

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, slack, fbs

There's definitely something wrong with `slack` in that after `fbs freeze`, I cannot run the standalone .exe file.

This is so weird because all other imports have no issues. For example, this simple code won't even work with `slack`

```
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

import slack
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appctxt = ApplicationContext()       # 1. Instantiate ApplicationContext
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.resize(250, 150)
    window.show()
    exit_code = appctxt.app.exec_()      # 2. Invoke appctxt.app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Steps to reproduce:

`pip install fbs PyQt5==5.9.2`

`pip install slackclient`

`fbs startproject`

`fbs run` <-- this works (can open up window)

`fbs freeze` <-- this works, no error

Then click on executable file from `~/target/name/name.exe` it won't even start.

Anyone can guess what the problem is?

```
Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio Code
Python 3.6.8 64-bit
```

Comment: If you remove the import of slack then does your .exe work? What version of pyintaller do you use?

Comment: yes it works by removing it. pyinstaller 3.5

Comment: Try using dependencywalker in your .exe to see if any dll is missing. Have you been able to package any application that only contains slack only with pyinstaller without using fbs?

Comment: maybe i should try dependencywalker although i don't know what this is yet. I initially tried with pyinstaller only, but ended up using fbs because pyinstaller alone did not work in my case

Comment: My strategy is to define the problem and know who is causing the problem, in your case you have already advanced on it: you know that one of the causes of the error is slack, but I also want to attack on the other hand: pyinstaller, forget about pyqt5 on the At the moment, that's why I ask you if you could generate an executable only with slack + pyinstaller without the influence of pyqt5, if you can't then the problem is a pyintaller bug, if instead you can then the problem is fbs.

Comment: yeah sure thanks. if you don't mind you can also try since it takes only a few steps to reproduce (it's okay if you don't want to). I just want to see if it causes the same problem with others.

Comment: I think you should try 'from slackclient import SlackClient'

Comment: no that's for the previous version. hmm.. i just can't figure this out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I f...king solved this.

It was not even related to `pyinstaller` nor `fbs`.

I checked every dependency installed in library. It turned out that the recent version for `multidict`(4.7.1) crashed with `slack-client` Downgrade to 4.6.1 solved the problem.
This was insane.

Comment: harsh reality.. someone posted [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict/issues/432) too.

Comment: this was not a pyinstaller bug. It was a bug from `multidict`